# Netlogon is missing?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, netlogon

By coincidence I noticed the "Netlogon" share on a Windows 2003 server is missing. Could you please explain what Netlogon is and how can I restore it?

Comment: Is the server in question a Domain Controller?

Comment: Yeah it's active directory 2003!

Answer (score 1):

It's a critical part of active directory.

Per Technet
Netlogon

> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services
>
> Description The Netlogon subkey stores information for the Net Logon
>   service.
>
> The Net Logon service verifies logon requests, and it registers,
>   authenticates, and locates domain controllers. Also, to maintain
>   backward compatibility, Net Logon manages replication of the user
>   account database to back up domain controllers running Windows NT 4.0
>   and earlier.

Restoring depends on how it became missing.

The netlogon share is different. It's a share on domain controlers for logon sripts.

> The administrative share for the scripts folder on Microsoft Windows
>   NT domain controllers at %SystemRoot%\system32\repl\import\scripts.
>   This share is used by the NetLogon service for the following purposes:
>   Storing a default user profile for users (which must be stored in a
>   subdirectory called Default User). If a user without a local profile
>   on his or her workstation or a server-based roaming profile logs on,
>   the default user profile is used.  Storing logon scripts (for example,
>   logon.bat).  Storing system policies (ntconfig.pol or config.pol
>   files).  When a client logs on to a Windows NT domain and is
>   authenticated, the final step in the logon process involves connecting
>   to the NetLogon share and downloading or applying any of the items in
>   the preceding list.

[Source](http://www.thenetworkencyclopedia.com/d2.asp?ref=1387)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257338

Comment: Thanks Alan for these information but my users can logon and I believe my system is running stable! I don't how I missed it. I discovered by asking a question on server fault check this page and you will understand how I discovered http://serverfault.com/questions/298047/push-new-registry-keys-via-group-policy

Comment: See my updated answer above.